# create frequency tables using rollapply() in R

Tags: r, apply

I have a data set like this:

Just 1 table with 2 columns. The first column runs from 1 to 100 and in the second we have random numbers. for eg

```
x    y
1    25
2    51
3    0   
-    --
48   250
49   500
50   1000
-    ---       --and so on till
100  600
```

Now , I need to choose a window of first 50 rows (x = 1 to x= 50).After this I need to find the range of these 50 y values, which is y[max]-y[min]. Then , I need to divide the range by 10 to create my frequency table. In the above example, range = 1000 - 0 = 1000. 1000/10 = 100.

so, my frequency table will look like

```
0 - 100   count value of y between 0 to 100 say i(0-100)
100 - 200 count value
```

and so on till

```
900-1000  count value.
```

I need to get total count value say " total ". After this, I need to take the ratio of respective count value to total count . For the first row , it would be i(0-100)/total.
For the second row , it would be i(100-200)/total and so on. Lets call these values as f. so, f1 = i(0-100)/total ; f2 = i(0-100)/total and so on.

After this , I need to compute summation [ f * ln(f) ]. So, our return value is      summation [ f * ln(f)] for the window from 1 to 50. After this , I need to slide this window by 1 position, which can be achieved by roll apply() function in R.

You can use this code to start :

```
library(zoo)
set.seed(1)
foo <- runif(100)
foo[c(58,59)] <- 0
rollapply(foo,width=50,FUN=function(xx){ ....})
```

I want some help to complete this "function(xx){ ....})" in the above code. I am struggling to put all the information that i said into this one small function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer...** I hope following will help you... Though its not exactly what you wanted

```
set.seed(1)
foo <- sample(1:1000,100)

#Rolling function
rollFreq = function(x, binCount){
  temp = hist(x, breaks = binCount, plot = FALSE)
  return = temp$counts
}

rollapply(foo, width=50, FUN=rollFreq, binCount = 10)

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    4    6    2    5    6    5    8    4    5     5
 [2,]    4    6    1    5    6    5    8    4    6     5
 [3,]    4    6    1    5    6    5    8    5    5     5
 [4,]    4    6    1    5    5    5    8    6    5     5
 [5,]    4    6    1    5    4    5    8    6    5     6
 [6,]    4    6    1    5    4    5    7    6    5     7
 [7,]    4    6    1    5    4    6    7    5    5     7
 [8,]    5    5    1    5    4    6    7    5    5     7
 [9,]    5    5    1    6    4    6    7    5    4     7
[10,]    5    5    2    6    4    6    7    5    4     6
[11,]    5    6    2    6    4    5    7    5    4     6
[12,]    6    6    2    6    3    5    7    5    4     6
[13,]    6    5    2    7    3    5    7    5    4     6
[14,]    5    5    2    8    3    5    7    5    4     6
[15,]    5    6    2    8    3    5    7    5    3     6
[16,]    5    5    2    8    3    6    7    5    3     6
[17,]    4    5    2    9    3    6    7    5    3     6
[18,]    4    5    2    9    3    6    7    5    4     5
[19,]    4    5    1    9    3    6    7    5    4     6
[20,]    4    4    1   10    3    6    7    5    4     6
[21,]    4    5    1    9    3    6    7    5    4     6
[22,]    4    6    1    9    2    6    7    5    4     6
[23,]    4    6    1    9    1    6    7    5    4     7
[24,]    4    6    1   10    1    5    7    5    4     7
[25,]    4    6    1   10    1    6    7    5    3     7
[26,]    3    6    1   10    1    6    8    5    3     7
[27,]    3    6    1   10    1    5    8    5    4     7
[28,]    3    6    1   10    1    6    7    5    4     7
[29,]    4    6    1   10    1    6    6    5    4     7
[30,]    4    6    1   10    1    6    5    5    5     7
[31,]    4    6    1   10    0    6    5    6    5     7
[32,]    4    6    1   10    0    6    5    6    5     7
[33,]    5    6    1    9    0    6    5    6    5     7
[34,]    6    6    1    9    0    6    5    6    4     7
[35,]    6    6    1    9    0    6    5    6    4     7
[36,]    6    6    1    9    0    5    5    7    4     7
[37,]    6    6    1    9    0    6    5    7    4     6
[38,]    6    7    1    9    0    6    5    7    4     5
[39,]    5    7    1   10    0    6    5    7    4     5
[40,]    5    7    1   10    0    6    6    6    4     5
[41,]    5    7    1   10    0    6    5    6    4     6
[42,]    5    6    1   10    0    6    6    6    4     6
[43,]    5    6    2   10    0    6    5    6    4     6
[44,]    5    6    2   10    0    6    5    6    4     6
[45,]    5    6    3    9    0    6    5    6    4     6
[46,]    5    6    3    9    0    6    4    6    5     6
[47,]    5    7    3    9    0    6    4    5    5     6
[48,]    5    7    3   10    0    6    3    5    5     6
[49,]    5    7    4    9    0    6    3    5    5     6
[50,]    6    6    4    9    0    6    3    5    5     6
[51,]    6    6    4    8    0    6    3    6    5     6
```

Comment: I get a strange error if I delete this part from your code:                      seqNo = as.numeric(seqNo),
    lower = temp$breaks[1:(length(temp$breaks)-1)],
    mids= as.numeric(temp$mids), 
    upper = temp$breaks[2:length(temp$breaks)],

Comment: My data is very large . It runs from 1 to 2 million not 100. It is very difficult for me to continue printing as this result as it takes long time. Is there any way to get my final result more efficiently , read faster.

Comment: Warning message:
In rbind(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 46)...............;;why do I get this message?

Comment: Because when frequency bins are assigned not all rolling groups (50 member each group) have values in all bins... I mean there might be possibilities that some groups don't have value in 0-100 bin and some don't have 901-1000... So its warning... You can take small sample and verify whether in warning case are you getting required results or not...

Answer (score 1):

What I could make out from your description is wrapped in the following function:

```
ff = function(x) 
{
   rg = range(x)
   f = prop.table(table(cut(x, 
                            do.call(seq, 
                                    c(as.list(rg), 
                                      list(diff(rg) / 10))))))
   sum(f * log(f))                                    
}
```

Using your "foo" I get:

```
sapply(head(seq_along(foo), (50 - 1)), 
       function(i) ff(foo[i:(i + (50 - 1))]))
# [1] -2.247295 -2.231095 -2.240361 -2.227678 -2.239769
# [6] -2.244925 -2.239769 -2.223568 -2.246704 -2.251620
#[11] -2.238672 -2.245751 -2.251015 -2.244540 -2.244540
#[16] -2.248029 -2.235686 -2.226600 -2.258055 -2.271002
#[21] -2.278686 -2.255815 -2.251620 -2.251620 -2.231593
#[26] -2.215659 -2.207976 -2.192042 -2.192042 -2.195029
#[31] -2.194966 -2.174102 -2.168838 -2.138807 -2.118781
#[36] -2.127867 -2.127867 -2.130853 -2.130853 -2.143801
#[41] -2.173831 -2.181514 -2.163534 -2.190973 -2.167729
#[46]       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: @user3683555 : `hist` uses `pretty` which means that (i) you don't always get the numbers of "breaks" you specify and (ii) your range of values gets modified. If these don't interfere with your work, then, I agree, `hist` is the best way to go.